# Swift undo feature, previously declared variable is always empty

Tags: swift, core-data, nsundomanager

I'm trying to implement an undo feature when deleting cells in a `UITableView`. The cell data to be deleted is declared as a variable. The deletion part works fine, however when I attempt to 'undo' the deletion the variable is always empty.

**Implementation**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowAction.Style.destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let selectedExercise = self.exercises[indexPath.row] 
        //selectedExercise is declared here to be used in both 
        //`deleteExercise` and `undoDeleteExercise`

        self.undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (selfTarget) in
            self.undoDeleteExercise(indexPath: indexPath, selectedExercise: selectedExercise)
        })

        self.deleteExercise(indexPath: indexPath, selectedExercise: selectedExercise)

        let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        message.text =  "Removing Exercise"
        let action = MDCSnackbarMessageAction()

        action.handler =  {() in
            self.undoManager?.undo()
        }
        action.title = "UNDO"
        message.action = action
        MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
    }
    return [delete]
}
```

**Deleting**
This works as expected. The selected exercise is removed from the database, exercises array and the `tableView`.

```
func deleteExercise(indexPath: IndexPath, selectedExercise: Exercise){
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let _ : NSError! = nil
    do {
        managedContext.delete(selectedExercise as NSManagedObject)
        exercises.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.execisesTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error : \(error)")
    }

    ifNoExercises()
}
```

**Undoing a Deletion**
The problem here is that `selectedExercise` is always an empty object, so although the row is added into the database and the `tableView` it does not contain any information.

```
func undoDeleteExercise(indexPath: IndexPath, selectedExercise: Exercise){
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let _ : NSError! = nil
    do {
        managedContext.insert(selectedExercise as NSManagedObject)

        exercises.insert(selectedExercise, at: indexPath.row)
        execisesTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error : \(error)")
    }

    ifNoExercises()
}
```

Comment: I don't use CoreData but perhaps the act of deleting an entity causes the reference to it to be cleared. Perhaps you should save a copy of the entity with the undo manager.

Comment: @rmaddy That's what i'm trying to do. In the implementation I save the selectedExercise as a variable and pass that to the undoDelete.

Comment: But that's not a copy, it's just a pointer to the same reference that is deleted.

Comment: @rmaddy That was it. I'm still a bit of a Swift beginner so didn't know it would be so easy haha. Thanks

Comment: @rmaddy If you'd like to put your comment into an answer I shall accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem this is how I fixed (this replaces `editActionsForRowAt`):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let exerciseEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: MyVariables.exerciseEntity, in: managedContext)!

        let copiedExercise = NSManagedObject(entity: exerciseEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

        let selectedExercise = self.exercises[indexPath.row]

        copiedExercise.setValue(selectedExercise.distance, forKeyPath: MyVariables.distance)
        copiedExercise.setValue(selectedExercise.end_time, forKeyPath: MyVariables.endTime)
        copiedExercise.setValue(selectedExercise.lat_lngs, forKeyPath: MyVariables.latLngs)
        copiedExercise.setValue(selectedExercise.map_string, forKeyPath: MyVariables.mapString)
        copiedExercise.setValue(selectedExercise.start_time, forKeyPath: MyVariables.startTime)

        self.undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self, handler: { (selfTarget) in
            self.undoDeleteExercise(indexPath: indexPath, selectedExercise: copiedExercise as! Exercise)
        })

        self.deleteExercise(indexPath: indexPath, selectedExercise: selectedExercise)

        let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        message.text =  "Removing Exercise"
        let action = MDCSnackbarMessageAction()

        action.handler =  {() in
            self.undoManager?.undo()
        }
        action.title = "UNDO"
        message.action = action
        MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}
```